# Is there a way to handle error such that the original sequence does not terminate?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

In the Error Handling section of the [reference guide](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#error.handling//) , I read and understood the following note that even if the errors are handled through the error-handling operators, the original sequence terminates. Is there a way to handle the error such the error in the stream is replaced by a value, and the original sequence continues?

"Before you learn about error-handling operators, you must keep in mind that any error in a reactive sequence is a terminal event. Even if an error-handling operator is used, it doesn’t allow the original sequence to continue, but rather converts the onError signal into the start of a new sequence (the fallback one). As such it replaces the terminated sequence upstream."

I can see situations (including my use case) where there are only some bad elements in a stream, and we do not want to terminate the entire stream because of that.

For example in the below code, assuming that n = 2 is a bad case, I just want gracefully handle it and not terminate the stream. May be I am missing something basic here.

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .map(n -> {if (n ==2) throw new IllegalArgumentException(); else {return "Successful-n";}})
        .onErrorReturn("Errored")
        .doOnNext(n -> log("Processed " + n))
        .blockLast();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to resubscribe to the observable, you can use the `retry()` operator. It will resubscribe to the observable when an error is detected. There are variations that take a retry count, or will provide different responses depending on the `Throwable`.

Edit: Observables are **defined** to terminate when an error occurs. So, in your example, you may have to wrap your error in a container such that you can carry on when the error is identified, rather than throwing an error at that point.

Comment: Thanks Bob. Although this might provide me with workable recourse, what I am seeking is a way to not having to subscribe to a fresh sequence. I just want an occasional error to be handled and the original sequence to continue.